# Display different result in different html div

Tags: jquery

This is my js file in which I am using jquery to verify login
problem: how can I differentiate the result in login_process.jsp i.e if the message is out.println"(Please Enter your Email)" I want to print it in `div id =targetDiv` and if the msg is  `msg.indexOf("Please Enter your Password")` I want to print it in `div id= targetDiv2`if both the fields are empty then above listed messages should appear in respective divs but none of them are displaying

How can I do this in jquery

```
hi again i have created a servlet given below                                                                           protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        /* TODO output your page here
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet loginServlet</title>");  
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet loginServlet at " + request.getContextPath () + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        */
        String uname= request.getParameter("user");
        String pass= request.getParameter("pass");
       if (uname.isEmpty())
       {
           response.setContentType("text/plain");
           response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
           response.getWriter().println("Please Enter Your Username");
       }
        if (pass.isEmpty())
       {
           response.setContentType("text/plain");
           response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
           response.getWriter().println("Please Enter Your Password");
       }
    } finally { 
        out.close();
    }
}                                                                           it has started to display messages in the div but unfortunately both of them appear in the same div as if they were a single message                                                                      i have also used response.getWriter().write() but in that case both messages appear as single line in   both  divs i know this is not the method u advised above can u help with it or add code lines the way u think it should be

//loginvalidate.js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //global vars
  var userName = $("#user"); //user name field
  var userPass = $("#pass"); //password field

//function to check name and comment field
  function checkCommentsForm(){
    //if(userName.attr("value") && userPass.attr("value"))
      return true;
    //else
      //return false;
  }

  //When form submitted
  $("#formL").submit(function(){

if(checkCommentsForm()){

      $.ajax({
        type: "post"
       , url: "loginProcess.jsp"
       ,data: "user="+userName.val()+"&pass="+userPass.val(),
       success: function(msg) {$('#targetDiv').hide();


           if(msg.indexOf("Please Enter your UserName") == 0){
           $("#targetDiv").html ("<h3>" + msg + "</h3>").fadeIn("slow");}

      if(msg.indexOf("Please Enter your Password") == 0){
            $("#targetDiv2").html ("<h3>" + msg + "</h3>").fadeIn("slow");
        }
       }

    });
        }
    else alert("Please fill UserName & Password!");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Obligatory note: Don't use JSPs for business logic, they're best suited as 'dumb' views that simply display the data they're passed. Any such logic should go into a servlet.
2. Your Java code could be written to better follow the [code-conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).
3. You can return a JSON object/array indicating the selector for jQuery along with the message to be displayed. Something like:

   ```
   [{"selector": "#targetDiv", "msg": "Please Enter Your Username"}, {"selector":"#targetDiv2", "msg":"Please Enter Your Password"}]
   ```

   It's probably best to use a [library](http://json.org/java/) to generate the JSON because doing it by hand is going to be error-prone and not very extensible. If you choose to use the JSON.org library, this is what you can add to your Servlet (please note you *will* have to download the library and add it to your project classpath and import it into your code to be able to use it - just like with any other Java library :

   ```
   JSONArray messages = new JSONArray();
   if(uname == null || uname.isEmpty())
   {
       JSONObject msg = new JSONObject();
       msg.put("selector", "#targetDiv");
       msg.put("msg", "Please Enter Your Username");
       messages.put(msg);
   }

   if(pass == null || pass.isEmpty())
   {
       JSONObject msg = new JSONObject();
       msg.put("selector", "#targetDiv2");
       msg.put("msg", "Please Enter Your Password");
       messages.put(msg);
   }

   response.setContentType("application/json");
   response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   response.getWriter().println(messages.toString());
   ```
4. The JavaScript for this will be something of the form:

   ```
   $.ajax({
           type: "post",
           url: "loginProcess.jsp",
           data: {user : userName.val(), pass : userPass.val()},
           success: function(data) {
                       if(data && data.length) { //expecting an array of error messages
                       //get each message and set it as the HTML for it's selector and fade in
                           for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                               $(data[i].selector).html(data[i].msg).fadeIn('slow');
                           }
                       }
                       else {
                           //successful login?
                       }
                   }
   });
   ```

   Note that it's better to send the data as an object to `.ajax()` rather than try and create the query string yourself.
5. If you choose to continue doing it the way shown in the example code you've posted, note that you're expecting `indexOf` to return `0` for both messages. This will only work when there's only one message. This will fail for the second message when both are returned. It is also the reason why you're seeing both messages in the same div because when you find one message, you print out *the whole string* (`msg`) into one div. So when you find the message for the username, you end up printing the entire `msg` string, which includes both messages, into the div `targetDiv`. The other check fails. I would suggest you drop this way completely.

Comment: where do i add this code [{"selector": "#targetDiv", "msg": "Please Enter Your Username"}, {"selector":"#targetDiv2", "msg":"Please Enter Your Password"}]

Comment: can u show me an example of complete code for the above example thanks

Comment: That is not code, it's the string representation of a [JSON object](http://www.json.org/) - my suggestion is to return JSON from your server-side component (preferably a servlet but it could be a JSP as well).

Comment: What do you mean 'complete code'? Where exactly are you stuck? I've already posted most of the JavaScript and pointed you to a JSON library for Java. Can you be more specific with what the issue is?

Comment: i have added a servlet in the above code it has started to display messages in the div but unfortunately both of them appear in the same div as if they were a single message  what i want is that when both fields are empty the message should be shown in their respective divs i have also used response.getWriter().write() but in that case both messages appear as single line in   both  divs i know this is not the method u advised above can u help with it or if i do ur way what exact line of codes would i have to add in the servlet

Comment: @ahsan I've pointed out in my updated answer *why* your getting both the messages in the same div. I would suggest against using this approach. Have you looked at the documentation for JSON and any JSON library at all? It is pretty simple and you could've had it up and running with just a few minutes of work. I've added some sample code though that can help you get started. You'll also find lots of examples online.

Answer (score 0):

Ahsan ,

You should clean up your code , all the backend should do is to get the status back.

Assume the above scenario , your jsp file should process the login and password and just send the status back to the UI sayings its success or failure

you should say

```
if(msg.Response.Status=="Success"){
}
else{
}
```

maintain a hidden P or div and just show the message.

Comment: hi kobe i have tried this by replacing index of with msg.Response.Status=="Please Enter Your Username" but it still not working do i need to do something else as well